# Serialize and Deserialize nested and foreign key with Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am creating an Ecommerce website and I am stuck in the backend trying to serialize and deserialize data using Django Rest Framework.

Here's my model file

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Company(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name


class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name


class Tags(models.Model):
    tag_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag_name


class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=999, null=True)
    product_description = models.TextField(max_length=999, null=True)
    product_price = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    product_company = models.ForeignKey(Company,null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tags)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    product_availability = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    stocks_count = models.DecimalField(null=True, decimal_places=1, max_digits=3)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name
```

**Here I have nested Many to Many relationships and Foreign Key relationship which I want to be able to read and write with DRF**

My Serializers file is as below:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *


class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return value.category_name

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('category_name',)


class TagsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return value.tag_name
    class Meta:
        model = Tags
        fields = ('tag_name',)


class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return value.company_name

    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('company_name',)


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tag = TagsSerializer(many=True)
    category = CategorySerializer(many=True)
    product_company = CompanySerializer()



    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('product_name','product_description','product_company','product_price','tag','category','product_availability','stocks_count')
```

So, I am not being able to Read/Write data with this code.

Here's my output:

`GET REQUEST`

```
 {
        "product_name": "Wedding Dress",
        "product_description": "It is a wedding dress",
        "product_company": null,
        "product_price": 200,
        "tag": [],
        "category": [],
        "product_availability": true,
        "stocks_count": "30.0"
    },
```

POST REQUEST

```
AssertionError at /products/post/
The `.create()` method does not support writable nested fields by default.
Write an explicit `.create()` method for serializer `Products.serializers.ProductSerializer`, or set `read_only=True` on nested serializer fields.
```

Comment: The error tells you exactly what you have to do, what is your question? https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations

Comment: I want to be able to POST and create a new object with DRF.

Comment: There are 2 ways to fix it: custom `create()` method in ProductSerializer or edit your data request (should include the object data of CategorySerialize, TagsSerializer, and ProductSerializer.

Comment: Yeah I solved it after reading the documentation.